# Inherit Composed look to subsites?

Tags: branding, out-of-the-box

At the moment I've added the attribute "ThemedCssFolderUrl" in the Onet.xml file and it works nicely. I got *7FA80357* from saving the custom composed look as a template and looked in the onet file. But this is a custom "id".

```
<Configuration ID="1" 
                Name="Default" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master" 
                ThemedCssFolderUrl="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/7FA80357">
```

But if we look at a "predefined look" the ***ThemedCssFolderUrl* ="_themes/0"** But i can't find if these potential standard design schemas in the sharepoint root.

Is there an **out of the box** way to make new Sub-Sites inherit the color theme from the root-site/Parent?